# moving different lines across the canvas with mouse in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i am trying to make a cropping feature in GUI. currently i can allow the user to draw a rectangle and perform a crop of the image on the canvas when the user unreleases the mouse. Once the rectangle is make i am trying to get the feature where the user can select one of the 4 lines of the rectangle and move it across the canvas thus changing the size of the crop box and cropping accordingly. this is what i have so far:

```
#these three functions draw the rectangle with end crop finding the start and end coordinates to perform the crop on
def startCrop(event):#gets coordinates when mouse clicked to begin crop
    global cropX
    cropX =event.x
    global cropY
    cropY = event.y
def drawRect(event):#draws rectangle of crop box
    panelB.delete("crop_rect")
    panelB.create_rectangle(cropX, cropY, event.x, event.y, outline='red', tag="crop_rect")
def endCrop(event): #gets dimensions and coordinates of rectangle crop box to performs crop on, performs crop and renders crop in panel C
    global cropX, cropY, endX, endY, croppedImg, thres, newHeight, croppedArray,ratio, newHeight,height,topLine,bottomLine,leftLine,rightLine
    cropXtemp = min(cropX,event.x)
    endX = max(cropX, event.x)
    cropYtemp = min(cropY, event.y)
    endY = max(cropY, event.y)
    cropX = cropXtemp
    cropY = cropYtemp
    panelB.delete("crop_rect")
    
    topLine = panelB.create_line(cropX,cropY,endX,cropY,fill='blue',width=2)
    rightLine = panelB.create_line(endX,cropY,endX,endY,fill='blue',width=2)
    bottomLine=panelB.create_line(cropX,endY,endX,endY,fill='blue',width=2)
    leftLine = panelB.create_line(cropX,cropY,cropX,endY,fill='blue',width=2)
    croppedImg = performCrop(thres)
    croppedArray = croppedImg
    setPanelC(croppedImg)
#these functions are my attempt of trying to selecting the lines and then moving them and adjust the other lines
def select_line(event):
    # Set the selected line's color to red
    panelB.itemconfig(event.widget, fill="red")
    # Store the starting coordinates of the selected line
    event.widget.start_coords = (event.x, event.y)

def move_line(event):
    # Calculate the change in x and y coordinates
    dx = event.x - event.widget.start_coords[0]
    dy = event.y - event.widget.start_coords[1]

    # Move the selected line by the change in x and y
    panelB.move(event.widget, dx, dy)

    # Update the other lines' coordinates
    panelB.coords(topLine, *panelB.coords(topLine)[0:2], panelB.coords(topLine)[2] + dx, panelB.coords(topLine)[3] + dy)
    panelB.coords(bottomLine, *panelB.coords(bottomLine)[0:2], panelB.coords(bottomLine)[2] + dx, panelB.coords(bottomLine)[3] + dy)
    panelB.coords(leftLine, panelB.coords(leftLine)[0] + dx, *panelB.coords(leftLine)[1:3], panelB.coords(leftLine)[3] + dy)
    panelB.coords(rightLine, panelB.coords(rightLine)[0] + dx, *panelB.coords(rightLine)[1:3], panelB.coords(rightLine)[3] + dy)

    # Update the starting coordinates of the selected line
    event.widget.start_coords = (event.x, event.y)


#this takes care of drawing the rectangle
panelB.bind("<Button-1>", startCrop)
panelB.bind("<B1-Motion>", drawRect)
panelB.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", endCrop)
#this takes care of moving the 4 lines
panelB.tag_bind(topLine, "<Button-3>", select_line)
panelB.tag_bind(rightLine, "<Button-3>", select_line)
panelB.tag_bind(bottomLine, "<Button-3>", select_line)
panelB.tag_bind(leftLine, "<Button-3>", select_line)
panelB.tag_bind(topLine, "<B3-Motion>", move_line)
panelB.tag_bind(rightLine, "<B3-Motion>", move_line)
panelB.tag_bind(bottomLine, "<B3-Motion>", move_line)
panelB.tag_bind(leftLine, "<B3-Motion>", move_line)
```

this draws the rectangle and then makes the 4 blue lines but when i click on them nothing happens. i expect it to change too red to indicate that it has been selected, but nothing happens.
i got most of this from chatgpt, and have been looking in youtube but no luck yet. If you have experience with moving/dragging different objects/lines across the canvas, i would appreciate the help.

Comment: Note that `event.widget` is the canvas, not the selected line.